# where can you download themes for jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid, themes

i can't find any links on [the main download page](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=6) for downloading themes for jqgrid.

am i missing something?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

jqGrid uses jQuery UI themes, which may be edited and downloaded from here: [jQuery UI - ThemeRoller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/)